# Define custom handle function for $.post ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
function getUsers()
{
    $.post("/admin/getusers",
    {
        username: username_input.val()
    }, showUsers(data));
}
```

ERROR: **Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined at getUsers**

How can i specify custom callback function for ajax request?

Comment: You are calling the function instead of passing it a parameter... wrap it with `function(data) {...}`

Comment: It looks like showUsers is the success function.  So `$.post(url, obj, showUsers);`

Comment: @James omg, how can i missed that. Make it an answer, so i can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like showUsers *is* your success function, so simply pass it as:

```
$.post("/admin/getusers", {
  username: username_input.val()
}, showUsers);
```

Comment: Nit: `showUsers` is not called (and shouldn't be). It should be *passed* to `$.post` so that `$.post` can call it.

Comment: @FelixKling fair enough :)

Comment: @FelixKling i think it was a typo)

Answer (score 1):

`data` should be an argument in a callback function definition, not a variable that you use as a parameter in a function invocation:

```
function callback(data) { /* data is available here */ }
```

You can pass this function definition as your callback argument:

```
 $.post("/admin/getusers", ...,  function callback(data) { /* data is available here */ });
```

And then call your `showUsers` inside the function body, where `data` is available when the function gets called after the response is received:

```
 $.post("/admin/getusers", ...,  function callback(data) { showUsers(data) });
```

Or to make it shorter, and ES6-y:

```
 $.post("/admin/getusers", ...,  data => showUsers(data));
```

Comment: Or even shorter: `$.post("/admin/getusers", ...,  showUsers);`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but as @James mentioned above, more convenient way to solve my problem was to pass just function name as a parameter. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Yeah if the function signature matches and you don't care about "this" then that works.